# how do i link a checkbox to a website

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, href

I have the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{ day.name }}-{{ $index }}" ng-model="slot.booked" ng-disabled="slot.booked">
        <label for="{{ day.name }}-{{ $index }}">{{ slot.time }}<br>
          <span ng-if="slot.booked">Booked</span>
          <span ng-if="!slot.booked">Available</span>
        </label>
```

Is there anyway that I can make it so that when the checkbox in clicked, it takes the user to another site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use the [ngChange directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()" />
```

And in the controller:

```
 $scope.change = function() {
   //opens a new tab in browser
   window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686170/how-do-i-link-a-checkbox-to-a-website', '_blank');
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ng06y90v/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [window.location.assign()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp):

#### HTML

```
<input ... ng-click="onclick()">
```

#### JS Controller

```
$scope.onclick = function() {
  window.location.assign("http://www.google.com")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
$scope.$watch('slot.booked', function(val){
    if(val){
       window.open('url', '_blank');
    }
});
```